SQL CHECKSUM returns different values when queried in SSMS and VS (Dapper og Entities)
The project goal is to be able to determine which records needs updating.
Two SQL servers, each running Comp.Level 150. One has a view that returns the checksum of several parameters (Uid, DateTime, int, Varchar ..). This is compared with a table on the other server. When they differ, a change has happend. At least that's the theory.
In SSMS they always match, whereas in C# (2022), running Dapper or Entity framework, the ref-server is always correct, whereas the src-view consistently returns the same false value.
(I don't think this is a duplicate question. If so, I'm sorry)
If I compare the two checksums they differ at the middle bytes, eg.
Src: 6DC8 D3BB
Ref: 6DCC 03BB
1000: 8  1101: D
0110: C  0000: 0
Endian issue?
The CHECKSUM returns INT but I notice that some 64-bit is going on:
Src: FFFF FFFF B4DD DA5B
Ref: FFFF FFFF B4C4 0A5B
1101: D  1101: D
0100: 4  0000: 0
(I use Windows calc to convert, I trust it 80% but haven't checked values)
Siggemannen: I know CHECKSUM means a risk of collisions and is deemed less reliable than HASHBYTES but it was not my decision.
Thom: In SSMS it's a simple "select checkvalue from  where id = @id" ... and that's the same script I use in dapper:  var result = db.Query(script, param), public class checksummodel { public int checkvalue {get; set;}}
The view uses CHECKSUM(field1(int), field2(uniqueidentifier...) ... fieldn()) as [checkvalue]. If you still want code, I will try to construct a generic demo that reproduces the thing.
CharlieFace: I have considered adding a fixed collation because it does indeed alter the result. That may be the key: perhaps SSMS makes some wizardry to accommodate this, ending up confusing me. I avoided this alteration because it means that I issue some 50k updates (which takes days). I'll discuss it with my colleagues after the weekend. I do however find it odd that the checksums differ the way they do, only one nipple in the middle bytes.

Please include the code you are using to get these values.

checksum is unreliable anyway, so even when you fix the bug in your code, i wouldn't use it for change tracking

@siggemannen What's unreliable about it?

It's always correct in SSMS but mismatches in .NET? What does the .NET code look like? Are you trying to write your own checksum in .NET?

Maybe they have different collations on the columns you are checksumming? What exactly are you doing to create the checksums on each server, please show.

@Charlieface when i used it to sync some stuff, i've had several collisions of same values even though the data was changed, and it was very small changes that did it. HASHBYTES is better

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Problem solved, thanks for all your input.
Server 1 has a view generating the checksum through a set of CTE's joined together in the CHECKSUM. It turns out that one of the CTE's returns records with the same timestamp, this resulting in a random sort order.
When selecting the sum, I would get one or the other even if no change had happened (I have told them not to use that field, but do they listen???)
I was way off but still I find it strange that the bit pattern between the two 32-bit checksums I got (hhhX Xhhh) consistently only differed in the X-bytes (as in 0000 XXXX and XXXX 0000).

Regarding the "... strange that the bit pattern between the two 32-bit checksums I got (hhhX Xhhh) consistently only differed in the X-bytes (as in 0000 XXXX and XXXX 0000)."
Did a small test and this is because of the crude CHECKSUM algorithm. Somewhere in the middle of the values I checksummed were the one that differed. If I changed the position the bits followed it.
